# Embed mp3 in html

Tags: html

I used this code for embed a mp3 file to html:

```
<EMBED SRC="mp3 link" HEIGHT=60 WIDTH=300>];
```

the problem is that the browser download the file and than he play it,
there is any way for do it in buffer or something like this?

because i want the user will not wait.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google has a good player :

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="audioUrl=MP3_FILE_URL" src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf" width="400" height="27" quality="best"></embed>
```

Comment: there is auto start for this?

Comment: As Google shut down reader, the new url is http://reader.googleusercontent.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf `<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="audioUrl=url.mp3" src="http://reader.googleusercontent.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf" width="400" height="27" quality="best"></embed>`

Comment: This answer might have been correct once, but not anymore. Flash will even be officially deprecated in a year or so. Accepted answer should be changed tot the one below,

Answer (score 17):

For browsers that support HTML 5 you can use this:

```
<audio src="song.mp3" controls="controls">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Otherwise you'd have to use JQuery as suggested above, or a flash audio player.

Comment: At the moment Firefox doesn't support mp3, and Safari and IE don't support ogg. You'll need to use something like `<audio controls autobuffer><source src="elvis.mp3"><source src="elvis.ogg"></audio>`, preferrably with some non-HTML5 fallback. ([Native Audio in the browser | HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/))

Comment: Firefox now supports mp3.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `audio` element of HTML5:

```
<audio src="[mp3 link]" preload controls></audio>
```